# Lately, after resuming from sleep, Ubuntu requires my modem to be rebooted to restore an Ethernet or Wi-Fi connection

Tags: networking, suspend

- I'm using Kubuntu 21.10 with kernel 5.13.0-22.
- It happens with both Ethernet, 2.4GHz Wi-Fi, and 5GHz Wi-Fi connections (two separate Wi-Fi networks).
- Things worked fine until this week.
- Rebooting the laptop does not help.
- The Windows installation on the same laptop does successfully connect.
- My Kubuntu live USB does successfully persist its connection through sleep, so it's something with my OS install.
- Rebooting the modem always lets me reconnect, but closing and re-opening the laptop lid will trigger the problem again.
- Removing the remembered connections from System Settings and re-adding them does not help.

I suspect this has something to do with DHCP business and assigned IPs, but I don't know anything about networking, so I'm not sure how to test or examine for that. I did install and then uninstall a large number of packages over the last 2 weeks, so I suspect I broke something in the process, e.g. by installing some package that replaces some built-in features, then uninstalling it without restoring the original's settings. Looking through my history, DNSmasq, Caddy, and Jellyfin-Server are the three packages that seem most obviously networking-related that got installed and removed lately.

What settings, services, potentially missing packages, etc should I look at first to help me diagnose this problem?

Comment: Please see my answer. If it helps to solve the problem, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 1):

Check these settings in Windows, as they can effect Ubuntu...

**Windows**

- boot into Windows
- open the Power control panel
- choose `change what the power buttons do`
- choose `change options that are unavailable`
- uncheck `fast startup`
- close the Power control panel
- open an administrative command prompt window
- type `powercfg /h off`
- type `chkdsk /f c:`
- approve to run chkdsk at next reboot
- reboot into Windows to let chkdsk run on drive C: